Brother and sister hood
Through a group on social random girl and me talked. First we both were willing to be best friends but after some time we both decided to be as brother and sister BC she doesn't have brother. And then we both attached to much to each other.we both have and had only Intention of a brother and sister no any other relation . But now we realised that maybe it is not allowed in islam being brother and sister by your own . And if it is not allowed so please give us a way through which we can talk BC we both are attached to eachother too much .

She is an ajnabi and she can not be your friend nor sister. The only thing you can do is either marry her or marry her mother or daughter, then she will be your mehram.

but we don't have any bad intentions.and i assure her to be my sister by heart. And thing to marry her is not possible. Bc I accepted him as a sister. She is an ajnabi but she is now my sister

She is not your sister, she is ajnabi. Just saying she is sister by your mouth does not make her your sister you are merely pretending. Your intentions dont matter she is ajnabi.


And the believers, men and women, are protecting friends one of
another; they enjoin the right and forbid the wrong, and they
establish worship and they pay the poor-due, and they obey Allah and
His messenger. As for these, Allah will have mercy on them. Lo! Allah
is Mighty, Wise. — (M. Pickthall translation) Quran 9:71

To all those who are mahrem (that is not related and whom you can marry), you should try not to be alone with her in secluded places, as there are chances of slipping into forbidden things.
